# Any cheap way to build Swift iOS without using VMs?

Tags: macos, xcode, swift

I need a way to build code that I do at home for a school project, at school we have macbook PROs so it's not a problem here, however it means I cannot keep working when I'm at home and that's not really productive.

If anyone knows about some cheap cloud macs or something like that, that would be located in Europe.

Comment: AWS has macOS services. But shouldn’t your school ensure that you have the necessary equipment? What is their position on this?